# How to get multiple keypress in python ubuntu?

Tags: python, ubuntu

I'm working on a python Ubuntu application in which I need to get multiple key presses even if my application is not in an active state (minimized). I need a piece of code that ables to work from background and counts number of key presses on any screen and anywhere. I've already tried it by using '**termios**' but it only works till my application is active (not minimized).

I am using **Quickly** python package for the application in which I've also tried Gdk's '**on_key_press_event**' but the problem remains the same. 
So please help me...Code is given below.

```
from locale import gettext as _
from gi.repository import Gtk # pylint: disable=E0611
from gi.repository import Gdk
from gi.repository.GdkPixbuf import Pixbuf, InterpType
import logging
import time
import os, sys
logger = logging.getLogger('myshotter')
from myshotter_lib import Window
from myshotter.AboutMyshotterDialog import AboutMyshotterDialog
from myshotter.PreferencesMyshotterDialog import PreferencesMyshotterDialog

class MyshotterWindow(Window):
    __gtype_name__ = "MyshotterWindow"

    key_counter = []

    def finish_initializing(self, builder): # pylint: disable=E1002
        super(MyshotterWindow, self).finish_initializing(builder)
        self.AboutDialog = AboutMyshotterDialog
        self.PreferencesDialog = PreferencesMyshotterDialog             
        self.keycounter = self.builder.get_object("keycounter")

    def on_key_press_event(self, widget, event):
        keyname = Gdk.keyval_name(event.keyval)
        #~ print "Key %s (%d) was pressed" % (keyname, event.keyval)
        self.key_counter.append(keyname)
        total_keys = len(self.key_counter)
        self.keycounter.set_text("No. of key pressed: "+str(total_keys))
```

Comment: Can you please provide some of your code and elaborate your requirements a bit more - you want to sniff the keyboard in X?

Comment: I'm using Quickly python package for building this Ubuntu application. When i run this application and then i press keys from the keyboard, it starts counting and displays the number of keys pressed but when i open other tabs or windows it doesn't count keys even if the application is running in the background. I want this application to count number of keys on any active window.